# Change font of specific rows to bold in forestplot

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, r-forestplot

I wrote a script using the "forestplot" package. I want to group the variables in certain categories, which I would like to show in bold, in order to accentuate those categories. How can i adjust my script, so that only certain rows, i.e Risk factor OR (95% CI), patient characteristics, medication history, comorbidities, surgical history and other are shown in bold? I have two colums and 18 rows. Can someone help me? I would be much grateful!!
My script is as below:

```
tabletext <- cbind(
  c("Risk factor" ,"Patient characteristics","Sex, male*", "Bmi (5 points)", 
    "Alcohol (5 units)", "Smoking*","Medication history",
    "Steroid use", "Anticoagulant use*","Comorbidities",
    "COPD GOLD 1/2", "COPD GOLD 3/4", "Other pulmonary disease",
     "Surgical history",
    "Previous colorectal surgery*", 
    "Previous abdominal surgery (other)","Other", "HIPEC*"),
  c("OR (95% CI)",NA, "1.78 (1.20-2.68)", "1.15 (0.95-1.38)", "1.04 (0.94-1.14)",
    "1.78 (1.11-2.80)", NA," 1.40 (0.68-2.67)", "1.55 (1.02-2.32)",NA, 
    "1.40 (0.70-2.61)", "1.56 (0.42-4.67)", "1.78 (0.63-4.28)",NA,
    "1.61 (1.03-2.49)", "0.80 (0.47-1.32)",NA, "4.14 (2.14-7.73)"))


?fpTxtGp
require(forestplot)
forestplot(tabletext,
txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = list(gpar(fontfamily = "Times",
                                   fontface="bold"),
                       gpar(fontfamily = "",
                                              col = "black"))),
  df_c,new_page = TRUE,
           boxsize = 0.2,
           is.summary = c(rep(FALSE,32)),
           clip = c(0,17),
  xlab = 'Odds ratio with 95% confidence interval
  * indicates significance',
  xlog = FALSE, 
           zero = 1,
  plotwidth=unit(12, "cm"),
  colgap=unit(2, "mm"),
  
           col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                          line = "darkblue",
                          summary = "royalblue"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what `df_c` is so I just created it based on your `tabletext` matrix:

```
df_c <- data.frame(mean = c(NA, NA, 1.78, 1.15, 1.04, 1.78, NA, 1.4, 1.55,
                            NA, 1.4, 1.56, 1.78, NA, 1.61, 0.8, NA, 4.14),
                   lower = c(NA, NA, 1.2, 0.95, 0.94, 1.11, NA, 0.68, 1.02, NA, 0.7,
                             0.42, 0.63, NA, 1.03, 0.47, NA, 2.14),
                   upper = c(NA, NA, 2.68, 1.38,1.14, 2.8, NA, 2.67,2.32, NA,
                             2.61, 4.67, 4.28, NA, 2.49, 1.32, NA, 7.73))
```

From there, its just a matter of adjusting the values passed to `is.summary`:

```
   forestplot(tabletext,
               txt_gp = fpTxtGp(label = list(gpar(fontfamily = "Times"),
                                             gpar(fontfamily = "",
                                                  col = "black"))),
               df_c,new_page = TRUE,
               boxsize = 0.2,
               is.summary = c(TRUE, TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4),
                              TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
                              rep(FALSE,3), TRUE, rep(FALSE,4)),
               clip = c(0,17),
               xlab = 'Odds ratio with 95% confidence interval
      * indicates significance',
               xlog = FALSE, 
               zero = 1,
               plotwidth=unit(12, "cm"),
               colgap=unit(2, "mm"),
               
               col = fpColors(box = "royalblue",
                              line = "darkblue",
                              summary = "royalblue"))
```

Which generates the following figure:

[image]