# Trying to create bold label in forestplot function

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am trying to create a bold label in the forrest plot function but have struggled. I have created my forrest plot with a table. Would appreciate any help. My code is below.

```
library(forestplot)

Fatigue_all_grade_sensitivity_analysis <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(1.41, 1.52, 2.92, 1.75),
                                                lower = c(1.30, 1.44, 2.59, 1.50),
                                                upper = c(1.52, 1.60, 3.30, 2.04),
                                                study = c("Prior or concurrent docetaxecel       use", "Single agent", "Double agent", "All Studies"),
                                                n = c("8117", "15381", "1945", "17326"),
                                                RCT = c("8", "16", "1", "18"),
                                                p = c("<0.01", "<0.01", "<0.01", "<0.01"),
                                                RR = c("1.41 (1.30-1.52)", "1.52 (1.44-           1.60)", "2.92 (2.59-3.30)", "1.75 (1.50-2.04)"))

plot <- Fatigue_all_grade_sensitivity_analysis |>
forestplot(labeltext = c(study, RCT, n,  RR, p), clip = c(0.5, 3.5), 
         xlog = FALSE, lwd.zero=0.5, vertices = FALSE, boxsize = 0.08, title= "All Grade
Fatigue Events") |>
fp_set_style(box = "darkgreen",
           line = "black") |> 
fp_add_header(study = c("", "Sensitivity Analysis"),
            RCT = c("", "RCT"),
            n = c("", "n"),
            p = c("", "p"),
            RR = c("", "RR (95% CI)")) |> 
fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 4, right_bottom_txt = fp_txt_gp("Favours agent", gp = gpar(cex = .9)),
              left_bottom_txt = fp_txt_gp("Favours Control", gp = gpar(cex = .9))) |>

print(plot)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the bold label, i see that some of the labels are bold like the title etc, which other part you want to be bold

Comment: So I would like the labels "All studies", "18", "17326", "1.75 (1.50-2.04)" and "P<0.01". Essentially the last row to signify overall results. I have specifically not used the is.summary function as it creates an unappealing diamond which in fact is not the pooled effect in this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: this might be handy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66151262/change-font-of-specific-rows-to-bold-in-forestplot

Comment: @Mark I have tried this before I posted and it did not work, kept getting errors. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this works. I used `fp_append_row`, we need to update is.summary=T, if FALSE it will not make the row bold, only for TRUE it will make it bold, but the appearance of the boxplot will be black and its shape will be diamond

```r
library(forestplot)
#> Warning: package 'forestplot' was built under R version 4.2.3
#> Loading required package: grid
#> Loading required package: checkmate
#> Loading required package: abind

Fatigue_all_grade_sensitivity_analysis <- tibble::tibble(mean  = c(1.41, 1.52, 2.92),
                                                         lower = c(1.30, 1.44, 2.59),
                                                         upper = c(1.52, 1.60, 3.30),
                                                         study = c("Prior or concurrent docetaxecel       use", "Single agent", "Double agent"),
                                                         n = c("8117", "15381", "1945"),
                                                         RCT = c("8", "16", "1"),
                                                         p = c("<0.01", "<0.01", "<0.01"),
                                                         RR = c("1.41 (1.30-1.52)", "1.52 (1.44-1.60)", "2.92 (2.59-3.30)"))

plot <- Fatigue_all_grade_sensitivity_analysis |>
  forestplot(labeltext = c(study, RCT, n,  RR, p), clip = c(0.5, 3.5), 
             xlog = FALSE, lwd.zero=0.5, vertices = FALSE, boxsize = 0.08, title= "All Grade
Fatigue Events") |>
  fp_set_style(box = "darkgreen",
               line = "black") |> 
  fp_add_header(study = c("", "Sensitivity Analysis"),
                RCT = c("", "RCT"),
                n = c("", "n"),
                p = c("", "p"),
                RR = c("", "RR (95% CI)")) |> 
  fp_decorate_graph(graph.pos = 4, right_bottom_txt = fp_txt_gp("Favours agent", gp = gpar(cex = .9)),
                    left_bottom_txt = fp_txt_gp("Favours Control", gp = gpar(cex = .9))) |>
  fp_append_row(mean  = 1.75,
                lower = 1.50,
                upper = 2.04,
                study = "All Studies",
                RR = "1.75 (1.50-2.04)",
                n="17326",
                RCT="18",
                p="<0.01",
                is.summary = T) |>
  
  print(plot)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>